# Istio and the custom HTTP method

Tags: istio

How to make Istio route custom HTTP methods?

```
$ curl -v -X MYMETHOD https://myapp.com
< HTTP/2 400 
< content-length: 11
< content-type: text/plain
< date: Wed, 29 Dec 2021 08:24:36 GMT
< server: envoy
< x-envoy-upstream-service-time: 1
< 
* Connection #0 to host myapp.com left intact
Bad Request
```

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: myapp
spec:
  gateways:
    - gw
  hosts:
    - 'myapp.com'
  http:
    - name: myapp
      route:
        - destination:
            host: myapp
            port:
              number: 8000
```

Kubernetes: 1.22.4
Istio: 1.12.1

Comment: Which Kubernetes and Istio version are you using?

Comment: Did you check if your endpoint works with a standard HTTP method? are there any logs in the istio-ingressgateway? You can turn on debug logging with: `istioctl proxy-config log istio-ingressgateway.istio-system --level debug`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Envoy does not support custom HTTP methods. Envoy implements the H/1 codec, which has a hardcoded list of HTTP methods it accepts (see [RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2616#section-5.1.1))

There is an open issue on the Envoy Github: https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/issues/18819

So you can't achieve what you want with an HTTP route. But you can make it work with a TCP/TLS route.

For this do the following:

1. Set the correct protocol on the `service istio-ingressgateway`:

```yaml
ports:
 - name: tcp
    nodePort: 8000
    port: 8000
    protocol: TCP
```

2. Change the protocol on the gateway port

```yaml
port:
  name: tcp-gateway
  number: 8000
  protocol: TCP
```

3. Configure your Virtual Service for TCP traffic:

```yaml
spec:
  gateways:
  - example-gateway
  hosts:
  - myapp.com
  tcp:
  - match:
    - port: 8000
    route:
    - destination:
        host: myapp.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 8000
```

With a TCP endpoint, you have to take into account that you can't apply host/path-based routing. So make sure your `myappp` VirtualService is the only service that serves that port.

Comment: As I need TLS termination I only had to add `protocol: TCP` to the deployment and `appProtocol: tcp` to the service.